# Ajax post to php. Save cookie and send it back to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am sending data to php via ajax POST. I want to save it in a php cookie, and then be able to retrieve it in javascript via a ajax GET request. In PHP, my cookie check function is returning "cookie ____ is not set". What am I doing wrong that is causing me not being able to store my cookie, and then retrieve it.

AJAX POST

```
function(config) {
    var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));

    //post cookie
    $.ajax({
           url: "php/pivot_cookie.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: config_copy,
           success: function(){ alert("Cookie: success") },
           error: function(data){alert(data);}
     });

}
```

PHP

```
$cookie_name = "pivot_config";
$cookie_value = $_POST['config_copy'];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, "/");

//cookie check function
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```

AJAX GET
I dont know what I put in the "data" field to retrieve the cookie so I can pass it into one of my other functions

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "php/pivot_cookie.php",
          type: "GET",
          data: (cookie - I dont know how to get it),
          success: function(){ alert("Cookie Retreival: success") },
          error: function(data){alert("Cookie Retrieval: failure");}
    });
}
```

Comment: `data` is not a required option for `$.ajax`

Comment: Yet again. I dont think you understand what a cookie is and how cookies work. [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) This whole process is unnecessary and makes no sence

Comment: Set a cookie in javascript in the browser `document.cookie` when the page is sent to the server the cookie goes too automatically. When the new page is returned from server to browser the cookie also goes back to the browser. If you want to change it on the server you can and it is returned in the new state, or you can change it on the browser and the new value goes back to the server with the next round trip. You definitely dont need to jquery post this stuff about, it makes no sence at all.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from not giving PHPs `setcookie()` what it wants for a 3rd parameter
you also needed to set one parameter for `$.ajax()`'s `.success()` method.

After that you can make `.success(data)` handle the `data` however you want.

**Note** the JSON data I am passing in place of the `data` property in the `ajax-post.html` file.

```
data: {"config_copy": config_copy}
```

Depending on the data you're handling you could just use Javascript to
retrieve the cookie data.

Try the below inside your web browser's Console? After you've set the cookie
( assuming you set only the one cookie `pivot_config`)

```
escape( document.cookie.split('=').pop() ).replace('+', ' ')
```

Also to note cookies are limited in the amount of data they can store.

### pivot_cookie.php

```
$cookie_name = "pivot_config";

if ( isset( $_POST['config_copy'])) {
    $cookie_value = $_POST['config_copy'];
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/");

    //cookie check function
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
}
else {
  if ( isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] ) ) {
    echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
  }
}
```

### ajax-post.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>getting using ajax</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function x (config) {
    var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));

    //post cookie
    $.ajax({
            url: "pivot_cookie.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"config_copy": config_copy},
            success: function(data,b,c){
              alert("Cookie Retreival: success");
              $("body").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){alert(data);}
        });

    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        x("hi post");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

### ajax-get.html

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>getting using ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "pivot_cookie.php",
          type: "GET",
          data: "(cookie - I dont know how to get it)",
          success: function(data,b,c){
            alert("Cookie Retreival: success");
            $("body").html(data);
          },
          error: function(data){alert("Cookie Retrieval: failure");}
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting a correct expiry on your cookie. Try:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600, "/"); // expire in 1 hour
```

[see official docs for setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie)