# how to print data sent by ajax post method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to post data and display it also. I am using ajax post method. I am able to get the event Id where data is saved, but not able to display the data. I searched a lot and got some answer also. I tried it in my code, but didn't got the result. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>POST API</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com      /ajax/libs    /jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="btn1">Check HTTP POST</button>
        <p>Display sample output from POST API:</p>
        <p id="one" />wEventId :
        <p id="two" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btn1").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'url',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        crossDomain: true,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: {},
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = data.result.wEventId;
                        },
                        failure: function(errMsg) {
                            console.log(errMsg);
                        }
                        var myData = data;
                        myData = new Array;

                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Anyone please help me how to modify the code to print the data saved. I have not given the url as it is an internal server and supposed not to disclose it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: p tag isn't self closing.

Comment: This might be useful aside from the `cookie` handling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821245/

Comment: @atinder but that's not giving any error

Comment: browser won't give you any error for incorrect html.

Comment: @ArchanaRoy Could you please show us your Complete json in the question itself.

Comment: For post event my API has been defined as url&key&nodeId&datasetId&status.In the status  I am giving the value which I need to send.I am not sure whether I should put this value with url itself or with data.The json format which I got with GET event is:"datasetId": "37", "datasetName": "eHealth - IIT Delhi", "datasetSource": "Data generated from medical sensors connected to the eHealth Kit", "relevantInformation": "NA", "attributeInformation": "NA", "acknowledgements": "NA", "mode": "shared", "contributor": "priyankaChauhan", "addedOn": "2015-04-10 14:27:46", "updatedOn": "2015-04-10 14:27:46"

Answer (score 0):

First I need to know, what is the structure of your json data.

Assuming that it is in a format like given below:

```
{"field_A":"value_a","field_b":"value_b"}
```

your code where you are trying to print as innerHTML should be like this:

```
success: function(data)
{
   console.log(data); 
   document.getElementById("two").innerHTML =     data.field_A;
},
```

Try to adjust accordingly.

I am still surprised from where are you getting the `result` of `data.result.wEventId`

Comment: My json data format is:  "datasetId": "37",
    "datasetName": "eHealth - IIT Delhi",
    "datasetSource": "Data generated from medical sensors connected to the eHealth Kit",
    "relevantInformation": "NA",
    "attributeInformation": "NA",
    "acknowledgements": "NA",
    "mode": "shared",
    "contributor": "priyankaChauhan",
    "addedOn": "2015-04-10 14:27:46",
    "updatedOn": "2015-04-10 14:27:46"

Comment: data.result.wEventId is giving me the node where the data is going, if I am correct.

Comment: In your format, you don't have the "wEventId" in the json. May be that's the problem its not getting printed.

Comment: when I checked my API on hurl.it I got this result : wEventId=" ". I tried the way you told data.field_A but its giving me undefined value. Only I am getting wEventId value.

Comment: They have defined separate API for get and getdataset. getdataset is working fine with get method to diaplay the data but with post method it was not working. Replacing it with get url, it worked. I am also new to rest API, so was trying with all possibility and finally got the solution.